# How to redirect to relative url htaccess apache 2.22

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the `rootdomain.com/index.php` to `rootdomain.com`, and just the root one, not any subdirectories also ending in `index.php`

I've tried

`Redirect 302 ^(.*)index.php$ /$1/`

`Redirect 302 ^(.*)index.php$ $1/`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1/ [R=302,L]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ / [R=302,L]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1/ [R=302,L,QSD]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ / [R=302,L,QSD]`

(I realize there are other questions like this. But the solutions in the other questions do not work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic rule to remove `index.php` from any relative or root path:

```
# remove index.php from root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: thanks a ton. apache syntax is pretty complex. seemingly unnecessarily so.

Comment: On the 3rd line, `^(.*)/index.\.php$` that enclosed regex seems like it should target any url ending in `index.php`, but it only redirects when the url is `{root}/index.php`. I actually prefer the latter behavior, but it seems weird to me that the `(.*)` seems to be having no effect

Comment: Actually there is a minor fix needed, try it now after browser cache clear.

Comment: is the change just to capture the `/` in the destination, or is it intended to capture subfolders?. In my tests, it didn't affect subfolders - it affected only the `root/index.php` url which I desire.

Comment: That is strange because on my Apache it is working as intended i.e. capturing all sub directories as well not just the root. Capturing a slash was needed as directories are supposed to have a trailing slash for security reasons.

Comment: what would be the correct way to target just the root level index.php, and not subdirectories?

Comment: Thanks a ton, @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.htaccess`, it should remove `index.php` from your URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```